# MathTransform doesn't work in Android project: "The type java.awt.geom.Point2D$Double cannot be resolved."

Tags: java, android, geotools

I need to transform coordinates using GeoTools. My code works fine in a Java project but when I put it in the Android I get the error at the mathTransform.transform(...) line: "The type java.awt.geom.Point2D$Double cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".
Here's my code:

```
CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:3765");
    CoordinateReferenceSystem targetCrs = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326");
    boolean lenient = true;
    double x, y;
    MathTransform mathTransform = CRS.findMathTransform(sourceCrs, targetCrs, lenient);

    parts = result.split(" ");
    String coors = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
        x = Double.parseDouble(parts[i]);
        y = Double.parseDouble(parts[i+1]);

        DirectPosition2D srcDirectPosition2D = new DirectPosition2D(sourceCrs, x, y);
        DirectPosition2D destDirectPosition2D = new DirectPosition2D();

        mathTransform.transform(srcDirectPosition2D, destDirectPosition2D);

        x = destDirectPosition2D.x;
        y = destDirectPosition2D.y;

        coors += x + " " + y + " ";
    }

    System.out.println(coors + ";");
```

Now I found this question which explains the reasons for it:  [Can't import Java awt in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924124/cant-import-java-awt-geom-in-eclipse), but what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1):

> what would be the solution?

You could not use this JAR, but instead find some other similar library that is ready for Android.

Or you could [read up on prior attempts to get GeoTools working on Android](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/Android).

Or you could contribute code changes back to the project that eliminate references to `java.awt` classes, replacing that code with algorithms implemented in the library itself.

Comment: Can I transform the cordinates differently, not using GeoTools?

Comment: @user1418018: By definition, yes. After all, GeoTools consists of Java code. You can write Java code. Other people can write Java code. There is nothing GeoTools has written that cannot be written by you or others. *How* you write such code, I cannot say, as I am an expert on Android, not geographic information systems. However, GeoTools is open source, and there are open source implementations of `ava.awt.geom.Point2D` available, and so you have all the code that you need.

Comment: I too have same problem. I am trying to use "org.apache.sis.core:sis-referencing:1.0" dependency for some conversion. But I am getting error as:     
             Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class org.apache.sis.geometry.DirectPosition2D, unresolved supertypes: java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double. I tried with geoTools also..But no luck.        can you tell what is missing ?

Comment: @RUBYKUMARI: As the error indicates, what is missing is `java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double`. Android does not have that. [Apache SIS is not compatible with Android](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SIS-350).

Comment: @CommonsWare: I am trying to use tools for epsg conversion. I got latLon from map and wants to convert it into EPSG 32644 format . So that I can retrieve feature data from map. Please suggest me which tool I have to use for my above requirement?

Comment: @RUBYKUMARI: "Please suggest me which tool I have to use for my above requirement?" -- that is not my area of expertise, sorry. https://gis.stackexchange.com/ might be able to help.