# Calculate if a point is inside a Polygon

Tags: java, math, geometry, polygon

I'm trying to check if a point contained in an ArrayList of points is inside a Polygon. The polygon and the points to check are structured as well:

```
private ArrayList<Pair<Float,Float>> polygon, points;
```

What my algorithm does, is to start from the first two point of the polygon and check if the point contained in **points** is contained in them. If not he will check again comparing the first with the third etc. until all the polygon array list has been scrolled. If the Boolean variable never becomes true, then it means that the point is not contained in the polygon. The problem is that with this method, it also find points that shouldn't be contained, such as in the image below:
[image]

If I draw something in the area between P1 and P2 it returns true even if there is clearly a part which is not in the shape. How can I improve my algorithm:

```
boolean between = false;
for (int j=0; j<points.size(); j++, between=false) {
    for (int i=0; i<polygon.size() && !between; i++) {
        float x1 = polygon.get(i).first;
        float y1 = polygon.get(i).second;
        for (int ii=0; ii<polygon.size() && !between; ii++) {
            float x2 = polygon.get(ii).first;
            float y2 = polygon.get(ii).second;
            if ((points.get(j).first < x1 && points.get(j).first > x2) &&
                (points.get(j).second < y1 && points.get(j).second > y2))
                    between = true;
        }
    }
    if (!between) scoreDrawOut = 1; else scoreDrawIn = 1;
}
```

EDIT: the method contains doesn't not get recognized.

```
private void checkDrawOut() {
    Path shape = new Path();
    for (int i=0; i<figura.size(); i++)
        shape.moveTo(figura.get(i).first, figura.get(i).second);
    boolean compreso = false;
    for (int x=0; x<segments.size(); x++) {
        ArrayList<Pair<Float, Float>> punti = segments.get(x);
        for (int j = 0; j < punti.size(); j++, compreso = false) {
            if (shape.contains(punti.get(j).first, punti.get(j).second))
                compreso = true;
        }
        if (!compreso) scoreDrawOut = 1;
        else scoreDrawIn = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any profound reason to *not* just create a https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html from the points and then simply call `path.contains(point)`?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

Comment: @Marco13 is it possible to convert that ArrayList in a Path?

Comment: You could use [`lineTo` and `moveTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html#method.summary) to construct the path.

Comment: I updated the method as suggested by @Marco13 but the method contains does not get recognized. I also updated the question so you can see.

Comment: Where did you import `Path` from in the code snippet? According to [one existing definition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) it refers to a *file system*, not graphics, path. `Marco13`'s suggestion was to use [`Path2D(.Double)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.Double.html) which is distinct from (and not even a descendant of) [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html).

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I cannot imports Path2D. When I do "import java.awt.geom.Path2D;" I get "cannot resolve symbol Path2D"

Comment: I'm developing it it Android Studio, it seems that it doesn't work

Comment: Ah-hah, Android. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924124/cant-import-java-awt-geom-in-eclipse). Also add `android` or `android-studio` to your tags.