# What does it mean to say that Java is native for Android and Objective-C is native for iOS?

Tags: native

By saying native code, we understand the code which is being executed by directly calling CPU or OS functions. Why do people say that Android went with Java, or Java is native for Android development when Java is being executed on VM? The same things you can for Objective-C and iOS. What is the reason people say that?

Comment: Mist people who say "native" don't know what it means,  They usually mean "normal" or "default".  C and C++ are native to Android.  Java is not.

Comment: Ok but what does it mean normal?

Comment: Your question doesn't have anything to do with the two languages you've tagged it with; nor does it really involve the OSes. It's simply asking for the meaning of the term "native". Don't re-add those tags.

Comment: Those 2 languages were selected as "native" to those 2 OSes. Therefore I want the attention of the people who have a good knowledge of them. And please don't delete tags. Sometimes the question does not have anything to with tags but you want the attention of a specific community.

Comment: That's not how tags work here. They're for categorizing questions, marking them according to their subjects, not just for getting attention. See the guidance in the [tag:objective-c] tag excerpt for when that tag should be applied; similar rules apply to all other tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of them are "native" to the OS. Both are languages, both get compiled.

- objective C will get compiled to assembly, that can be directly run by a processor
- java will get compiled to byte code that will be interpreted by a JVM (namely dalvik)
- since Android 4.4, a new virtual machine appeared for Android : [ART](http://pocketnow.com/2013/11/13/dalvik-vs-art), it will get all bytecode compiled in assembly, but this is still experimental for now.

With Objective C you could argue that the language used to create apps is the same as the language to code the OS. For Android is would be more difficult to say so. The OS is build mostly in C, some parts in Java, but Android API themselves are also made of a mix of C and Java.

Answer (score 0):

Android Native Library, allows you to implement parts of your app using native-code languages such as C and C++, allows you write native code. JAVA - is not native. On the byte-code level, Android doesn't use Java. The source is Java, but it doesn't use a JVM.

WHY JAVA? Android runs on many different hardware platforms. You would need to compile and optimize your native code for each of these different platforms!
[Why does Android use Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560963/why-does-android-use-java)